# How to group 2 columns flex items in responsive screen

Tags: html, css, reactjs, flexbox

I need help on CSS flexbox in responsive screen.

This is the flex container and items in desktop screen
[image]

As you can see, the container has flex and flex-wrap applied.
The each column is  and `flex: 1 1 auto;` applied.

And in mobile screen, I would like to make like this:
[image]

I applied `flex: 0 1 50%` to display 2 columns in one row.
But I want to:

**1. (required) group the orange always side by side no matter the screen size. **
2. (optional) and it doesn't matter (make it flexible by checking the height?) displaying 2 columns in 1 cell (like green and purple items in single cell)

Not sure if this makes sense, if anything is unclear, I'll comment or update the post, please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

The only way i can think of to keep them as you want is if green and purple are wrapped in one div. After that it just a matter of determine `flex-basis` and reposition when needed with `order`

```css
.flex {
    display: flex;
}
.flex > div {
    flex: 1 1 calc(100% / 7);
}
.flex > .d2-wrap {
    flex-basis: calc(100% / 7 * 2);
    display: flex;
}
.flex > .d2-wrap > div {
    flex: 1 1 auto;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    .flex, .flex > .d2-wrap {
        flex-wrap: wrap;
    }
    .flex > div, .flex > .d2-wrap {
        flex: 1 1 50%;
    }
    .flex > .d2-wrap > div {
        flex-basis: 100%;
    }
    .d4 {order: 1;}
    .d5 {order: 2;}
    .d1 {order: 3;}
    .d2-wrap {order: 4;}
    .d6 {order: 5;}
    .d7 {order: 6;}
}

.d1 {background: pink; height: 150px;}
.d2 {background: red; height: 100px;}
.d3 {background: green; height: 50px;}
.d4 {background: purple; height: 150px;}
.d5 {background: lightblue; height: 150px;}
.d6 {background: orange; height: 150px;}
.d7 {background: darkorange; height: 150px;}
```

```html
<div class="flex">
    <div class="d1"></div>
    <div class="d2-wrap">
        <div class="d2"></div>
        <div class="d3"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="d4"></div>
    <div class="d5"></div>
    <div class="d6"></div>
    <div class="d7"></div>
</div>
```